Tkinter invalid command name ".!toplevel.!frame5.!entry"
When I am trying to run this entry form I keep getting an error message:
 in save_event
event_listbox.insert(tk.END, entry['Event Name'].get())
File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1644, in cget
return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!toplevel.!frame5.!entry"

I am not sure what the invalid command is.
def create_event_form():
form = tk.Toplevel(root)
form.title("Create New Event")

entries = {}
fields = ['Event Name', 'Date', 'Time', 'Participation', 'Ideal Weather']

for field in fields:
    row = tk.Frame(form)
    label = tk.Label(row, width=15, text=field, anchor='w')
    entry = tk.Entry(row)
    row.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X, padx=5, pady=5)
    label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    entry.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.X)
    entries[field] = entry

tk.Button(form, text="Save Event", command=lambda: save_event(entries, form, 
entry)).pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)
def save_event(entries, form, entry):
wb = load_workbook('School_Events.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
new_row = sheet.max_row + 1
sheet.cell(row=new_row, column=1, value=entries['Event Name'].get())
sheet.cell(row=new_row, column=2, value=entries['Date'].get())
sheet.cell(row=new_row, column=3, value=entries['Time'].get())
sheet.cell(row=new_row, column=4, value=entries['Participation'].get())
sheet.cell(row=new_row, column=5, value=entries['Ideal Weather'].get())
wb.save('School_Events.xlsx')
form.destroy()
event_listbox.insert(tk.END, entry['Event Name'].get())
messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Event created successfully!")

I have tried different variations such as creating new variables trying to get the data from the entry box a different way.

You need to call .get() on your Entry before calling .destroy() on the window containing it.

The indentation isn't correct.

You haven't provided us with the function save_event, which actually causes the error.
